# Word for a moniker that you use to address friends

Tags: single-word-requests, hailnames

What is the word for the words we use to address a person or people to whom we stand in a particular relationship.

For example I usually address my friends as "boss". I greet them with "Hey boss, how are you doing?"

Neighbouring words or terms include *term of endearment* which doesn't fit as *endearment* seems too affectionate a word for the context to which I'm referring.

Similarly *pet name* is too affectionate and it's also used to tag a specific person *rather than a collection of people*.

NB: Apologies if my wording is unclear.

Edit: Emphasised collection of people to clarify why *pet name* or *nickname* aren't appropriate in my context.

Comment: You are making this question kind of hard by already preempting for yourself what could be useful answers: _monikers_, _terms of endearment_, and _pet name_.

Comment: The "boss" example is specific to you. Do you mean the category that includes words like "bro", "dude", "buddy", etc?

Comment: @user405662 I've explained why I've omitted those two terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might talk of *casual terms of address* in general for such terms as "pal", "buddy", "mate",  etc. However, the terms you are referring to are of another sort, they are apparently a very  personal choice of yours among terms not  used for that purpose; for this reason you might talk of *(highly) idiosyncratic terms of address*.

Answer (score 0):

OED:

**nickname,** n.

> 1. **A (usually familiar or humorous) name which is given to a person, place, etc., as a supposedly appropriate replacement for or addition to the proper name.**
>
> 1984   M. Scammell Solzhenitsyn (1985) iii. 77   *In early adolescence, when he suddenly grew much taller than the others, he earned the nickname of ‘Ostrich’.*
>
> 2001   Vanity Fair (N.Y.) May 219/2   *In negotiations, Grossman exuded a menacing charm; around Greenwich Village, his nickname was ‘the floating Buddha’.*

$10 word - high register: **sobriquet** n. (also found spelled as *soubriquet*) **An epithet, a nickname.**

> 1867   A. Trollope Last Chron. Barset II. xlix. 57   *Her name was Susan, but he had always called her Posy, having himself invented for her that soubriquet.*

Comment: That example of Anthony Trollope's actually clinches it neatly.

Comment: A nickname - in my experience at least refers to a specific person rather than a word for a more general form of address.